# Where should component fetch logic be placed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

For a vue component `Page` I retrieve its data (or maybe props?) `title` and `content` from a REST request. When should I execute this REST fetch request? And where should the logic reside?

Right now I attempt to fetch on component `ready` but this function is never executing:

```
<template>
    <b-container class="bv-example-row">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>

        <b-row>
            <b-col>
                {{content}}
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </b-container>
</template>

<script>
import api from '../../api'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            id: '',
            slug: '',
            title: '',
            content: ''
        };
    },

    ready() {
        console.log('foo');
        this.fetchData();
    },

    methods: {
        fetchData() {
            api.getPageBySlug('sample-page', page => {
                this.$set('title', page.title);
                this.$set('content', page.content);
            });
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `ready()` hook does not exist in Vue.js 2.

You could place your Ajax code in many hooks. It is more common to use one of [the following **lifecycle hooks**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram):

- `beforeCreate()`
- `created()`
- `beforeMount()`
- `mounted()`.

What should guide your decision, then? There's somethings you must consider.

**First:** Vue's initialization code is executed **synchronously**.

This means, technically, any asynchronous code you run in any of those hooks will only respond **after** all of those hooks end. See demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  beforeCreate() {
    setTimeout(() => { console.log('fastest asynchronous code ever (started at beforeCreate)') }, 0);
    console.log('beforeCreate hook executed');
  },
  created() {
    console.log('created hook executed');
  },
  beforeMount() {
    console.log('beforeMount hook executed');
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('mounted hook executed');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Check the console.
</div>
```

In other words, if you make an Ajax call in `beforeCreate`, **no matter how fast** the API responds, the response will only be processed way later, way after the `created()` has been executed.

## Which hook to use?

- Need just to trigger a call as soon as possible?

  - Use `beforeCreate()`
  - Why?

    - It runs sooner than any of those hooks, but...
- Need to **read from or modify `data`** right away?

  - Use `created()`
  - Why?

    - [State is only initialized between `beforeCreate()` and `created()`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.5.16/dist/vue.js#L4613-L4617), so if you [**assign some data before `created()`, it would be lost**](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/gxt6xr1p/).
- Need anything that is generated after `created()`?

  - Use `beforeMount()`
  - Why?

    - I don't know anything that isn't available at `created()` and is available at `beforeMount()` [**other than the compiled `this.$options.render`  render function**](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/ow2Lrf1c/) (see [source as well](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.5.16/dist/vue.js#L2739-L2765)), so this case must really be a rare situation.
- Need anything from the DOM (e.g. a `ref`)?

  - Use `mounted()`
  - Why? Because those are only available at the `mounted()` hook.

## When using Vuex to manage state globally

As [mentioned in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675422/where-should-component-fetch-logic-be-placed/49675482?noredirect=1#comment86362533_49675482), a common approach is to use Vuex to manage your application's state globally. In that case, the requests should be started in [**Vuex actions**](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html). Your component, then, in any lifecycle hook (or method), would dispatch the actions. See demo below.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
strict: true,
  state: {
    people: []
  },
  mutations: {
    populate: function (state, newPeople) {
      state.people = newPeople
    }
  },
  actions: {
    fetchPeople ({ commit }) {
      axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users').then(function (response) {
        commit('populate', response.data.data)
      }, function () {
        console.log('error')
      })
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('mycomp', {
  computed: Vuex.mapState(['people']),
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li v-for="p in people">
      {{ p.first_name }} {{ p.last_name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `
});

new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('fetchPeople');
  },
  computed: Vuex.mapState(['people']),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  In parent:
  <ul>
    <li v-for="p in people">
      {{ p.first_name }} {{ p.last_name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
  In custom component (the very same data, fetched only once):
  <mycomp></mycomp>
</div>
```

Comment: The doc includes a nice image of a [Vue instance lifecycle](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram).

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that a commonly used approach is to store each result globally, vuex is the most used state management library for vue. In this case you'd trigger an action in the hooks, instead of the request itself. The action will trigger the request and fill the store with data, which can then be used across all components. This will save a lot of traffic when multiple components use the same endpoint. It also keeps your data across components synchronized nicely.

Comment: @PhilipFeldmann good point, also. I built a demo exposing that situation. Please let me know if you have any other thoughts about it! Thanks!